# Jquery each inside each affects only the last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I have problem with nested loops. Please take a look on the fiddle below:
http://jsfiddle.net/7znfmp9o/

I want each section to get parallax effect however something strange is going on here. .each() code is applied only for last element within the loop.

Changing this line:

`$bgElm = $(this).find('.swiper-slide-bg, .mk-section-video')`

into this:

`$bgElm = $('.parallax-true').eq(0).find('.swiper-slide-bg, .mk-section-video')`

runs the snippet on desired section, however iteration on `.eq(i)` doesn't work either, even within closure:

`(function(i){ ... })(i);`

What am I missing here? Thx for your help

Comment: Keith Clark posted this article on pure CSS driven parallax sites. Something to look into http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/pure-css-parallax-websites/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to this line:

```
 $bgElm = $(this).find('.swiper-slide-bg'),
```

You are setting the contents of this internal variable every time the first forEach occurs.  When the event is raised the value of this is the last element in the forEach loop. You should move these variables outside of the forEach loop and append elements into it. Then once the event is raised for loop on the elements within this variable.

I put together a VERY crude implementation of what I am proposing. While it works, you should reorganize the data structures and give proper naming to help describe your intentions. For instance, **$bgElm** is a poor variable choice for a variable describing the set of parallax-ed elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/myqswjnt/